# How to use order by in UNION query using eclsipe link JPA?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using eclipse link as my JPA. I have following sql query that uses a UNION and ORDER BY.

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM RQST p WHERE  RQST_ID ='14962709' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM RQST q WHERE PARNT_RQST_ID IN (SELECT RQST_ID FROM RQST WHERE  
PARNT_RQST_ID  ='14962709'))ORDER BY RQST_DT_TM;
```

This is working fine now I want to convert this in to JPQL. I have written following in my code

```
select req from 
( select req from Rqst req WHERE ( req.parntRqstId =:PARENT_REQUEST)  
  UNION select reqs from Rqst reqs where reqs.parntRqstId in 
    ( select req.rqstId from Rqst req  WHERE (req.parntRqstId =:PARENT_REQUEST) 
  ) 
)
ORDER BY req.rqstDtTm
```

But this is throwing

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.
An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Can any one tell me where it went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could reformat your JPA query in order to reach the same effect, using the OR condition:

(query not tested, so consider changing it)

```
select req from Rqst req WHERE ( req.parntRqstId =:PARENT_REQUEST)  
    OR reqs.parntRqstId in ( select req.rqstId from Rqst req  WHERE (req.parntRqstId =:PARENT_REQUEST) )) ORDER BY req.rqstDtTm
```

Alternatively use native queries for that.

PS: There is no support for UNION in JPA, but in EclipseLink there is.

Comment: thq. yes JPA does not support but eclipse link does support this. my formation of query is problem here. I would like to test your suggestion.